# With only 16 weeks left in the PSYD program, the school put a hold on my account

Tags: thesis

I apologize if my statement is wordy and all over the place. The entire situation is a bit emotional for me, so I am trying to figure out how to best explain the circumstance from a factual, unbiased, and objective standpoint. Please take a read and bestow me with your guidance. Thank you!

My PsyD Experience at Touro University Worldwide is as follows In 2017, I enrolled in their Human and Organizational Psychology online doctorate program.  The dispute occurred sixteen weeks away from being done with the PSYD program and deep into my thesis I experienced an abrupt halt. At the Mid to end of 2019, after I had written my proposal and gained the approval of the school’s (IRB) Institutional Review Board to conduct my research study. Approximately 4-6 weeks after IRB approval and well into the next term.  The administrative staff informed me I had been dropped from the course that I thought I had been attending for the past  8 weeks and wouldn’t be able to register for the second to last course in the doctoral program.

According to the TUW  and the Registrar, my dissertation chair,  forgot to input my grades from the last courses I had enrolled and completed, of which included the course where I obtained IRB approval. (I have emails stating I completed the tasks required to move forward, from my dissertation chair and the PSYD department director).  The bursar and registrar both informed me of the hold on my account. There was an outstanding balance of $1,000 for the extension course. What extension course? Without my knowledge, the registrar dropped me from the course I had enrolled in and completed more than half of, and after I secured financial aid for the term. Thus,   I chose a leave of absence to save up $1,000.

When I had the $1,000, approximately 6 months thereafter and requested  reinstatment into the program, the bursar stated I now owed $8,000 out of pocket, $4,000 they required up front to reinstate.

The information gets confusing because I could not get a straight answer from anyone. For months I had attempted to contact admin and could not get any concrete information why there was a hold on my account. the Bursar explained that because my grades we missing, they presumed I was unreliable and not allowed to apply for financial aid to pay for school. Instead, I had to pay TUW for paying my financial aid disbursement back to the department of education.  I had maintained a 3.9  and ranked among the top 5% of the students in TUW’s MA’s in Industrial and Organizational Psychology Summa Cum Laude 4.0.  And for the preceding 4 close to 5 years, I had received financial aid. TUW claimed they paid FAFSA $8,000 to cover the cost of my financial aid disbursement and living allowance.  Financial Aid policy is as follows, if you drop a class early in the term, you don’t have to pay back the loan instead you give back the money right away.  If you drop a course after a set date, after the second or third week of the term, then the student keeps the financial aid disbursement then the repayment is the the student’s obligation.  Never have I encountered or heard of a time when a higher learning institute repays a FAFSA loan disbursement and living allowancce that the student kept.

I’m very confused and not sure what to do because I’ve attempted to contact their Bursar and my dissertation chair with with little to no responses or from my perspective, unhelpful.

What I would like to happen is to be given the opportunity to use and apply for financial aid like I normally would to pay for the class and and not be required to pay 4000 up front and 8000 total out-of-pocket. I would be happy to continue working with my dissertation chair, and if she declines then perhaps the support of my dissertation committee members would suffice. I just really want to finish, more than anything in the world!

(I am not sure I use the right legal jargon, or if this paragraph is worth adding to my dispute)

In an ideal world I would be able to finish the program. As well as  compensated for the emotional damage that I experienced as a direct result of the lack of communication from TUW administration and faculty as well as the for the inability to finish my the program resulted in a loss of career opportunities, and a loss of professional opportunities that depended on completing my research and obtaining the doctoral degree. One such lost opportunity was Dr. Georg Lind’s invitation to speak at the Moral Democracy Symposium in Germany 2020. As a formal complaint is structured on factual assessments, I will forego discussion of my subjective experience.

TUW Mission Statement: “The mission of Touro University Worldwide (TUW) is to offer online degree programs to serve the needs of adult learners (service to society), professionals (intellectual pursuit), and the underserved (social justice). TUW is committed to offering doctoral, graduate, bachelor and associate degree programs to support this mission. The mission is also shared through the campus-based undergraduate education programs at Touro College Los Angeles Division which serves a specific student body. Together, the campus based and online programs contribute to the achievement of the overall Touro core values driving this mission to provide opportunities for those who are underserved, provide service to society and achievement of the overall Touro University Worldwide student success”.

As a mixed race female first generation immigrant, who is classified as living under the poverty level and currently resides in section 8 housing program- I may fit the description of underserved peoples.  The Bursar did not make any statements regarding finding ways to help me to get back in school. His voice changed becoming increasingly fast and louder, as we discussed my predicament. He also, was unable to provide me with any documentation of their decisions to drop me.

On a side note, I fell into a deep state of depression since I had put my entire life and soul into my work or so it felt like it and I had been working up to this point and so close to finishing that it was hard for me to accept it first. I was thinking I would just conduct my research anyways but I believe  conducting my research out of school is against IRB regulations. I reached out to my dissertation chair, asking if she would like to still help me reach my goal. No response. I emailed the director, no response. The admin, from my perspective, lacking in solutions and/or  empathy.

Comment: Has the correct grade been inputted for the class you completed and were not given credit for?

Comment: From my perspective, this is not going to get resolved unless you can get your dissertation advisor and hopefully your departmental chair on your team to sort this out. Have you tried contacting other committee members? Also, consider reaching out to the office of diversity, equity, and inclusion for any tips they might have on working with the fAFSA situation.

Comment: @Dawn, that is probably the core of an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Alethia,
I have over 20 years of experience in higher education, specifically teaching and administration in doctoral psychology programs offering the PsyD.  First, Dawn is wise to recommend building bridges with the department leadership and your dissertation chair.
Second, begin documenting EVERYTHING.  If you have the capacity to audio record telephone calls, do it.  If you have the ability to record video conferences, do it.  If not, take detailed notes both during and after all conversations, especially noting who, when, and what about interactions.  When you send an email, be sure to track when it is received and when it is opened.  Better than email, if you have the telephone number of the administrator or your chairperson, call.  Call methodically, documenting the frequency of your efforts.  At the same time you are contacting PsyD faculty, be sure to reach out to student services.  in the catalog for telephone numbers.  Call in the morning, call at noon, and call at the end-of-business.  Leave brief polite messages.  If these efforts fail to gain allies, it will be time to act on your own behalf
It all begins with your student handbook and/or university catalog.  These contain any binding conditions related to your education with the school.  It will also contain policies and procedures related to changing grades, appealing grades, appealing university decisions, etc.  These documents lay out all the rules, policies, and procedures for actions, and appeals of actions.  These docs will be the first thing any "referee" or "adjudicator" will examine. For example, from the [2019-2020 catalog](http://studentservices.tu.edu/catalog/2019-2020_TUC_Catalog.pdf) about grade appeals.

> Grade Appeal Process
> -- Once final grades have been submitted, a failing course grade may be changed only by the course faculty.
> The grade appeals process varies according to a student’s academic program. Students must see their
> academic program handbook for details. The decision of the course faculty will be communicated to the
> Registrar in writing within two instructional days of when the appeal was approved

Know their policies and procedures better than they do.  **Know them like the back of your hand.**

Finally, I would recommend two additional steps taken simultaneously in conjunction with the above efforts.  **One A**, I would contact the California Bureau for Private Postsecondary Education in the Department of Consumer Affairs.  They have a page discussing https://www.bppe.ca.gov/enforcement/complaint.shtml making complaints.  And **One B**, contact an attorney experienced in helping students navigate problems with university administrations. You can google search "higher education lawyers for students California"

I hope this helps.
~mwm